# list comprehension of tuples from dict and lists

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to figure out how to create a list of date:vessel tuple combinations from the following data:

- A list of vessels
- A list of vessel arrival dates
- A list of dates in a planning timelines

The (vessel, date) needs to contain all possible vessel:date combinations in the date horizon FROM the vessel arrival date (A vessel cannot leave before it has arrived).

**Desired output: Example**

```
horizon dates = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03']
vessels = ['A']
vessel_arrival_date = {'A':'2020-01-02'}
```

vessel 'A's arrival date is '2020-01-02', therefore the tuple of possible departure dates is:

```
departure_date_tuple = [('A', '2020-01-02'), ('A', '2020-01-03')]
```

I have tried two methods within a comprehension so far using a pandas dataframe to extract the dates

```
departure_dates = [(vessel, date) for vessel in vessels for date in sorted(dates_ser.loc[vessel_notice_of_readiness_date[vessel]:, 'dates'])]
```

however these yields **every** vessel/date combination and does not account for the fact that a vessel cannot depart before it has arrived.

Data below:

```
dates = ['2020-05-28',
 '2020-05-29',
 '2020-05-30',
 '2020-05-31',
 '2020-06-01',
 '2020-06-02',
 '2020-06-03',
 '2020-06-04',
 '2020-06-05',
 '2020-06-06',
 '2020-06-07',
 '2020-06-08',
 '2020-06-09',
 '2020-06-10',
 '2020-06-11']

vessels = ['AM OCEAN SILVER',
 'APJ ANGAD 2',
 'AQUATONKA',
 'ARUN',
 'BAY OF NAPLES',
 'BOMER OYSTER',
 'BULK JAPAN',
 'CCSC YASA JING',
 'CEYLON BREEZE',
 'CHANG HANG HAO HAI',
 'FURIOUS',
 'HAIFA ROSHANA',
 'HARALAMBOS',
 'IKAN PULAS',
 'KANG XIN HAI',
 'MAMBO',
 'MOORING LINE',
 'PACIFIC MAJOR',
 'PELICAN',
 'PETER OLDENDORFF',
 'ROBUSTO',
 'Rahi',
 'SHTP',
 'CCSC ROBERTS BANK',
 'SUNRISE',
 'TIN CITY',
 'XIN FA HAI',
 'YASA UNITY']

vessel_arrival_date = {'CEYLON BREEZE': '2020-05-29',
 'PETER OLDENDORFF': '2020-05-29',
 'BULK JAPAN': '2020-05-29',
 'XIN FA HAI': '2020-05-29',
 'PACIFIC MAJOR': '2020-06-01',
 'CCSC YASA JING': '2020-06-01',
 'CHANG HANG HAO HAI': '2020-06-01',
 'ROBUSTO': '2020-06-01',
 'AQUATONKA': '2020-06-02',
 'ARUN': '2020-06-02',
 'HARALAMBOS': '2020-06-02',
 'MAMBO': '2020-06-02',
 'SHTP': '2020-06-05',
 'FURIOUS': '2020-06-05',
 'YASA UNITY': '2020-06-05',
 'AM OCEAN SILVER': '2020-06-05',
 'PELICAN': '2020-06-06',
 'BAY OF NAPLES': '2020-06-06',
 'TIN CITY': '2020-06-06',
 'MOORING LINE': '2020-06-06',
 'KANG XIN HAI': '2020-06-09',
 'Rahi': '2020-06-09',
 'APJ ANGAD 2': '2020-06-09',
 'SM ROBERTS BANK': '2020-06-09',
 'HAIFA ROSHANA': '2020-06-10',
 'IKAN PULAS': '2020-06-10',
 'SUNRISE': '2020-06-10',
 'BOMER OYSTER': '2020-06-10'}
```

Comment: Is using list-comprehension a requirement? What about doing it with other tools?

Comment: It is not a strict requirement no - ultimately this will end up as a pulp variable dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates,vessels], names=['dates','vessels']).to_frame(index=False)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(vessel_arrival_date, orient='index').rename(columns={0:'ArrivalDate'})
list_of_Depart = df1.merge(df2, left_on='vessels', right_index=True)\
                    .query('ArrivalDate <= dates')\
                    .set_index(['vessels','dates']).index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[('AM OCEAN SILVER', '2020-06-05'),
 ('AM OCEAN SILVER', '2020-06-06'),
 ('AM OCEAN SILVER', '2020-06-07'),
 ('AM OCEAN SILVER', '2020-06-08'),
 ('AM OCEAN SILVER', '2020-06-09'),
 ('AM OCEAN SILVER', '2020-06-10'),
 ('AM OCEAN SILVER', '2020-06-11'),
 ('APJ ANGAD 2', '2020-06-09'),
 ('APJ ANGAD 2', '2020-06-10'),
 ('APJ ANGAD 2', '2020-06-11'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-02'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-03'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-04'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-05'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-06'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-07'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-08'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-09'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-10'),
 ('AQUATONKA', '2020-06-11'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-02'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-03'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-04'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-05'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-06'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-07'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-08'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-09'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-10'),
 ('ARUN', '2020-06-11'),
 ('BAY OF NAPLES', '2020-06-06'),
 ('BAY OF NAPLES', '2020-06-07'),
 ('BAY OF NAPLES', '2020-06-08'),
 ('BAY OF NAPLES', '2020-06-09'),
 ('BAY OF NAPLES', '2020-06-10'),
 ('BAY OF NAPLES', '2020-06-11'),
 ('BOMER OYSTER', '2020-06-10'),
 ('BOMER OYSTER', '2020-06-11'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-05-29'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-05-30'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-05-31'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-01'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-02'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-03'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-04'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-05'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-06'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-07'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-08'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-09'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-10'),
 ('BULK JAPAN', '2020-06-11'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-01'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-02'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-03'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-04'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-05'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-06'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-07'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-08'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-09'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-10'),
 ('CCSC YASA JING', '2020-06-11'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-05-29'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-05-30'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-05-31'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-01'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-02'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-03'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-04'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-05'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-06'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-07'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-08'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-09'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-10'),
 ('CEYLON BREEZE', '2020-06-11'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-01'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-02'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-03'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-04'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-05'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-06'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-07'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-08'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-09'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-10'),
 ('CHANG HANG HAO HAI', '2020-06-11'),
 ('FURIOUS', '2020-06-05'),
 ('FURIOUS', '2020-06-06'),
 ('FURIOUS', '2020-06-07'),
 ('FURIOUS', '2020-06-08'),
 ('FURIOUS', '2020-06-09'),
 ('FURIOUS', '2020-06-10'),
 ('FURIOUS', '2020-06-11'),
 ('HAIFA ROSHANA', '2020-06-10'),
 ('HAIFA ROSHANA', '2020-06-11'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-02'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-03'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-04'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-05'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-06'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-07'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-08'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-09'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-10'),
 ('HARALAMBOS', '2020-06-11'),
 ('IKAN PULAS', '2020-06-10'),
 ('IKAN PULAS', '2020-06-11'),
 ('KANG XIN HAI', '2020-06-09'),
 ('KANG XIN HAI', '2020-06-10'),
 ('KANG XIN HAI', '2020-06-11'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-02'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-03'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-04'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-05'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-06'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-07'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-08'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-09'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-10'),
 ('MAMBO', '2020-06-11'),
 ('MOORING LINE', '2020-06-06'),
 ('MOORING LINE', '2020-06-07'),
 ('MOORING LINE', '2020-06-08'),
 ('MOORING LINE', '2020-06-09'),
 ('MOORING LINE', '2020-06-10'),
 ('MOORING LINE', '2020-06-11'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-01'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-02'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-03'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-04'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-05'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-06'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-07'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-08'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-09'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-10'),
 ('PACIFIC MAJOR', '2020-06-11'),
 ('PELICAN', '2020-06-06'),
 ('PELICAN', '2020-06-07'),
 ('PELICAN', '2020-06-08'),
 ('PELICAN', '2020-06-09'),
 ('PELICAN', '2020-06-10'),
 ('PELICAN', '2020-06-11'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-05-29'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-05-30'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-05-31'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-01'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-02'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-03'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-04'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-05'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-06'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-07'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-08'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-09'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-10'),
 ('PETER OLDENDORFF', '2020-06-11'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-01'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-02'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-03'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-04'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-05'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-06'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-07'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-08'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-09'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-10'),
 ('ROBUSTO', '2020-06-11'),
 ('Rahi', '2020-06-09'),
 ('Rahi', '2020-06-10'),
 ('Rahi', '2020-06-11'),
 ('SHTP', '2020-06-05'),
 ('SHTP', '2020-06-06'),
 ('SHTP', '2020-06-07'),
 ('SHTP', '2020-06-08'),
 ('SHTP', '2020-06-09'),
 ('SHTP', '2020-06-10'),
 ('SHTP', '2020-06-11'),
 ('SUNRISE', '2020-06-10'),
 ('SUNRISE', '2020-06-11'),
 ('TIN CITY', '2020-06-06'),
 ('TIN CITY', '2020-06-07'),
 ('TIN CITY', '2020-06-08'),
 ('TIN CITY', '2020-06-09'),
 ('TIN CITY', '2020-06-10'),
 ('TIN CITY', '2020-06-11'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-05-29'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-05-30'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-05-31'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-01'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-02'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-03'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-04'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-05'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-06'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-07'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-08'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-09'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-10'),
 ('XIN FA HAI', '2020-06-11'),
 ('YASA UNITY', '2020-06-05'),
 ('YASA UNITY', '2020-06-06'),
 ('YASA UNITY', '2020-06-07'),
 ('YASA UNITY', '2020-06-08'),
 ('YASA UNITY', '2020-06-09'),
 ('YASA UNITY', '2020-06-10'),
 ('YASA UNITY', '2020-06-11')]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after - thank you very much....I would have never have thought of going about it in this way!